# How to add an id to a native ios screen

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I'm using detox on a hybrid app. I'd like to use by.id in native code

Currently I'm logging in like this:

```
  try {
// 'Email address' is the input's placeholder text
await waitFor(element(by.text('Email address')).atIndex(0))
  .toBeVisible()
  .withTimeout(TIMEOUT);
await expect(element(by.label('Email address')).atIndex(0)).toBeVisible();
await element(by.label('Email address')).atIndex(0).typeText(config[email].email);
} catch (err) {
  // Email addresses get cached, so you won't find the text 'Email address' after the first login
} finally {
  await element(by.label('Password')).atIndex(0).typeText(devConfig[email].password);
  await element(by.label('Sign in')).atIndex(0).tap();
}
```

I want to do something like this.

```
await element(by.id('email')).typeText(devConfig[email].password);
await element(by.id('password')).typeText(devConfig[email].password);
await element(by.id('login')).tap();
```

How can I add ids to native ios inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testID` is mapped on iOS to `accessibilityIdentifier`. So if you set that to the desired value, you will be able to match it using `by.id()`.

Answer (score 0):

I added an accessibilityLabel and used by.label.
https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Matchers.md